# Building an error summary in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

My form is bound to an object that implements `IDataErrorInfo` and it validates correctly on a field by field basis. I would like to have some way to summarize the results based on the fields on the form, and not the `Error` property of `IDataErrorInfo`. Is there a way I can loop through the controls somehow and determine which controls are invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to answer your question using IDataErrorInfo, but I'm not sure what you wanted. Did you want to avoid using IDataErrorInfo completely? If so, I can post another answer to your question perhaps, but it would involve implementing your own ValidationRule class and adding it to your XAML.

Comment: I want to continue to use IDataErrorInfo.

Answer (score 0):

To do this MVVM way, you must collect all the errors in ViewModel first. That is, find which all properties are validated as false, then add error text for all such properties to a collection/list/array and then use this collection/list/array to show the errors in error summary on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest, but I'm not quite sure what you mean "summarize the results based on the fields on the form". I think what I'm suggesting should allow you to do whatever you want though.

I would recommend you use IDataErrorInfo and work with your objects and its fields rather than specific controls. In my base class for all my ViewModels (Data you are displaying), I implement IDataErrorInfo like this

```
private Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public virtual string Error
{
    get { return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors); }
}

public bool HasErrors
{
    get
    {
        return errors.Count > 0;
    }
}

public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string result;
        errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out result);
        return result;
    }
}

protected void SetError<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop, String error)
{
    String propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(prop);

    if (error == null)
        errors.Remove(propertyName);
    else
        errors[propertyName] = error;

    OnHasErrorsChanged();
}

protected string GetError<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop, String error)
{
    String propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(prop);

    String s;
    errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out s);
    return s;
}

protected virtual void OnHasErrorsChanged()
{

}
```

And then, I can implement a property like this for use in data binding to store the validation errors:

```
public String ProjectName
{
    get { return projectName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != projectName)
        {
            projectName = value;
            SetError(() => ProjectName, ValidateProjectName());
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ProjectName);
        }
    }
}
```

**To get any field's error**

```
String error = GetError( () => SomeField ); // OR
String error = this["SomeField"];
```

Or you can use Errors to get a list of all errors

---

**Note** In this example I'm using SetError which I implemented and **RaisePropertyChanged** which is implemented in Prism's **NotificationObject** class. The **NotificationObject** class simply implements **INotifyPropertyChanged** and gives you a refactor-safe version of PropertyChanged("PropertyName") called RaisePropertyChanged that I pass the lamda expression.

If you do not use Prism, you can simply make SetError take two strings (property, error). Or, implement the  PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName method yourself to make use of this refactor-safe version.

e.g.

```
public static class PropertySupport
{
    public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        if (propertyExpresssion == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
        }

        var memberExpression = propertyExpresssion.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue I'm running into is dealing with a large object graph, and validating parent/child objects/collections. Each class right now is validating itself.

Comment: @MikeCole If I were you, I would still be validating outside of my UI code. I'm not sure of your specifics, but if I had a large object graph in a window I might have something like this: my window has a ViewModel called SomeDataViewModel which has a reference to the Object graph. It would then implement the validation which would traverse the graph and validate each item but this can be done all in the one place now. I guess you may have to be more clear on what result you want (how are you displaying the error? what are you using to trigger validation? etc.)

Comment: I'm implementing IDataErrorInfo and setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the binding to trigger the validation. Each bound control validates properly but I'm just trying to get the summary of all validation errors. Was hoping I could scrape the elements on the form to get this.

Comment: @MikeCole I see.. I still believe you are probably doing it the right way already. In WPF, it is usually more difficult to deal with the controls directly than it is to work with the underlying data being displayed. If each item in the object graph already implements IDataErrorInfo and validates itself correctly, then why not just traverse the graph (of data objects) using a BFS and create a list off all the IDataErrorInfo.Error values?

Comment: => Using a BFS - what does that mean?

Comment: @MikeCole Sorry, breadth-first-search, a graph search algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search I would perhaps use something like this to collect all the validation errors

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That's kind of what I was leaning towards although it would be a bit painful because the framework isn't very flexible. I was hoping to find a quick and easy workaround in the UI.